# Check multiple Document exists id Firestore Collection

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I want check within a list of 10 document IDs how many exists in a collection. One way to do it would store the document ID inside the document and use `in` operator.

```
const result = await this.afs.collection(path).where('id', 'in', ['doc1', 'doc2']).get();
```

Is there a way we can avoid storing the document id inside document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular query, you can use [FieldPath.documentId()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldPath#static-documentid).  It returns a token that you can use in the field path of the query:

```
this.afs.collection(path).where(FieldPath.documentId(), 'in', ['doc1', 'doc2'])
```

I've linked you to the plain JavaScript documentation.  If you're using Angular, it might have a slightly different way of getting this token value, but it will be in a class called `FieldPath`.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thx a lot!!